# Why won't my Python code connect to Spotify's API?

Tags: python, api, spotify, python-idle, spotipy

I am trying to connect to Spotify's API in Python on Idle and I keep running into this error.  My friend tested my code on her laptop and it compiled correctly, but it won't work when I run it.  This is my code (My client and secret id are covered) and the output:

[python error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olJ6v.png)

It says there is no Spotipy module, but I can confirm that I installed it in my command center and restarted my laptop, but it still won't recognize it as a module.  Why am I getting this error if the code works on my friends laptop?  This is the output I should be getting:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSm65.png)

Comment: "I can confirm that I installed it in my command center" **What does this mean**? What is a "command center"?

Comment: My bad typo, I meant that I already installed spotipy in my command prompt for windows.  My python code works running it directly in the command prompt, but not when I run it in Idle for some reason because I won't recognize that I downloaded it

Comment: Okay, I understood it properly, then. The general form of this question (it is the same problem, for a wide variety of libraries - because the problem is with the *installation process*, not the library) is a *very* common question, but there is not yet a good reference Q&A pair. I am currently working on one, and will add this question to the duplicates list when I am ready.

Answer (score 0):

if you installed with pip.
it could be you have to do:

```
pip3 install spotipy
```

rather than

```
pip install spotipy
```

hope this helps

Comment: So I had already used those commands to install on my command prompt.  I tried to run it again in Idle and came up with the same error again, but then I opened my command prompt again and ran the code directly from there, and weirdly enough it connected to the API and returned the desired output.  I'm not sure why it won't work in Idle, but running it in command prompt seems to work fine.  Thanks !

Comment: You likely have more than one python.exe installed.